# What curved ramp transports a ball from (1,1) to (0,0) most quickly, under the acceleration of gravity, with no friction or air resistance?

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

An infinitisemally small ball is placed at the top of a ramp which has a height of 1m and ends 1m away horizontally. What is the optimal curve of the ramp to minimize time taken for the ball to reach the base? I've tried a spreadsheet simulation of quadratic, cubic, circular and cycloidal functions; and the best so far seems to be the cycloid. Is this true; can it be proven? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is a cycloid. Please look under *bratistochrone*.

Comment: [Brachistochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Brachistochrone_curve).

Comment: The _prototypical_ calculus-of-variations problem -- the one that started the field!  (And probably _one more_ reason for Johann and Jacob Bernoulli not to be speaking to one another...)